# XAMPP don't know how to restart

Tags: xampp

I want to restart it because I made some changes in the php.ini to adjust the `max_file_size`. I need to restart it so that it will take effect however I can't find the command in the XAMPP control panel. I tried to search in Google I can't find the right answer. By the way, I am using XAMPP 1.7.4 in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the version I am using, from the control panel just click the stop button for the given app and then the start button.

Comment: The Xampp root on Windows is usually c:\xampp.  You probably have a problem with your install.  At the end of the install there is a text-based configuration wizard that you need to complete.  Also, in case you are using Windows x64,  1.7.4 is somewhat broken on this platform - uninstall and use 1.7.3.

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to scrap XAMPP over this issue. There are no missing or buggy .dlls in the newer versions that I know about. The control panel just has to be run as administrator in Vista or Windows 7.

Right click the control panel shortcut or .exe file icon.
Click on properties.
select the compatibility tab.
then in the privliege level box at the bottom, check the "Run this program as an administrator" box.

Click apply and then load up XAMPP.

Comment: To the top with this answer. Thanks, it  makes sense and worked

Comment: thanks it worked for me too, I was also looking for it and was thinking some thing wrong with xampp, but solution was only to run it as administrator lol. :)

Comment: That's a big ol +1. This should really be the answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can go to your xampp instalation directory, and run

```
xampp_stop.exe
xampp_start.exe
```

This will restart Apache and Mysql.

Only Apache:
    apache_stop.bat
    apache_start.bat

Or use the control panel, by clicking on Stop, then Restart, on the Apache line Service.

More info at http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1173

Answer (score 2):

you can also kill the httpd (apache) process and then start apache again from xampp control panel

Comment: That's what I tried to do but it says ERROR -1. Prior to that it says : This program must be run from your XAMPP root directory. Where is that? I installed it in C:\xampp.

Comment: maybe you should reconfigure xampp. You can do this by running in cmd setup_xampp.bat (in xampp directory). The utility will prompt you for a couple of things...and also for the xampp root directory - this is what i remember the last time i did this when i moved the directory to another disk/directory

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php), or lamp in linux. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)'s a guide how to enable in ubuntu linux.

Comment: I used wamp server. The reason I wanna use xampp because I want to learn Perl also.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, I had a problem restarting the XAMPP Apache server from the XAMPP  Control Panel until I brought up the XAMPP Control Panel by right-clicking it and choosing "run as administrator". After that, I could stop and restart Apache using the control panel buttons just fine.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can send the `restart` command to `lamp`.

Depending on where `lamp` is installed, this could be

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: I know this isn't answering the original question as that asks for Windows. Linux users may end up on this page before they realise the question relates to Windows, as it's not the question title, so I feel the answer is justified.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering an old post, but I want to add to the public record so that people don't waste time looking for answers (like I did).  This post seems to show up a lot during google search.

I am using win7 32bits, and I have been running xampp for a while, but with only up apache for php files.  I am currently trying to test APC caching, so I searched how to get APC to work with xampp.  I followed the instructions on the popular pages and downloaded the apc dll file, but nothing worked.

To get to the point, from my experience, xampp versions 1.7.4 to current (1.7.7) do not work and are full of bugs.  These versions do not have the APC dll included with them and the downloaded apc dll files don't work, despite some reports in postings that they do.  I could not stop apache or mysql with these versions, they errored out.  These versions also have processes that don't terminate when I chose to shut down xampp, therefore I couldn't uninstall them completely, their main folders couldn't be deleted.  I did not check which processes were which, but I was able to delete/uninstall the xampp folders only after I restart windows.

The version that works without errors (none that I can see) is version 1.7.3.  It does not have any control panel error, you can start/stop apache without errors, and you can actually terminate xampp.

Version 1.7.3 also comes with the php_apc.dll file that is compatible and actually works.  Unlike the newer versions, the php.ini file actually contains the php_apc.dll extension line, all you have to do is remove the semicolon in-front of that line and save.  Go to the xampp control panel and stop/restart the apache process.  APC will be activated.  To check, click on the admin button in the control panel and click on phpinfo(), do a text search for apc and you will see the apc's configuration.

Xampp 1.7.3 is running php 5.3.1, but it should not matter unless you have any requirement for a higher php version to test your php code.

Answer (score 1):

in windows 7 go to xampp folder, 
then go to apache folder -> then to bin folder
there you will find something called apache monitor
you can use this restart the apache services

It works fine