# how can i change max_file_uploads?

Tags: php, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP see only 20 uploading files at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083179/php-see-only-20-uploading-files-at-a-time)

I tried changing it in `php.ini` development and production. but still I am unable to upload files more than 20 at the same time. I have checked current setting using `phpinfo();` but still showing `max_file_uploads` is `20` not showing changed value in `php.ini`.

Comment: What is your Development enviroment?

Comment: did you restart the php/apache server?

Comment: im a newbie i dont know development environment, but i download XAMPP

Comment: sir what do you mean by restart?

Comment: Also, what PHP version are you using?

Comment: @user1933652 XAMPP is a web server. If your code works then the server is running. You need to shut it down and then start it again. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275499/xampp-dont-know-how-to-restart

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php.You should edit your max_file_upload limit and then restart the apache server

Comment: i tried stop then start in xampp control panel but it still didnt work!

Comment: There are multiple php.ini files. Check which php.ini file is loaded and confirm that you have changed in same php.ini file. You can check it by php_ini_loaded_file() function. May be it helps.

Comment: @BhavikShah The guy is in windows and he's using xampp so there's only one php.ini file.You have to change 2 values in php.ini to increase upload size.Check my solution.

Comment: nothing happens with php_ini_loaded_file() function

Comment: @MevinBabu: If there is only one php.ini in Xampp, then can you please tell me why phpinfo is still showing old config when he has changed it in one php.ini. Just a question out of curiosity.

Comment: @user1933652: Please check this URL. It might help you little.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php

Comment: Maybe because of his cache or he might have 2 copies of XAMPP on his system!

Comment: I have a problem i stop apache in xamppp control panel and ican't start it again!!!!

Comment: @user1933652 Do not panic . Some other application must be using the port.Check how may XAMPP is running and also check if any messenger,skype or other internet applications are running.If running then disable them and try again.As a last resort try restarting your computer

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but phpinfo() still show max_file_uploads 20

Comment: can you tell where you have installed your xampp ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to change the values in `php.ini` file.Your *php.ini* file is in `xampp\php\php.ini`

You have to change both these values to be able to upload bigger files,

Example to change it into 100Mb set :

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

*Note: After you edit your `php.ini` file restart xampp or apache server to see the difference.*

Comment: i have a question where should i change it develpment or production?

Comment: @user1933652 change in both because i dont know in which mode your XAMPP is currently working in.