# Why its showing file was not found in laravel while submitting the form?

Tags: php, laravel

I am submitting form at admin side and i need to upload multiple images and need to do multiple fields entry which take several time but sometime i suddenly get error like your file was not found and sometime it's work perfectly fine

Comment: It might be your file was too large to upload that taking time. And with small files it's working.. if this is the case?

Comment: No when i try again it working with the same files.

Comment: show your code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

I think its your php ini issue

Update your `php ini file` `upload your php ini shee max size`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065496/8863063

Comment: r u uploading multiple images in laravel ?

Comment: Yes, i am uploading approx 30 images and sometime its working fine and sometime i am getting this stupid error and when i try again then again it's working.